# Apache2 cannot open .php files

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, cakephp

I installed lamp long time ago and was able to execute php files. However, recently I tried to install cakePHP and ran into trouble (restarting apache started to generate errors). Thus I purged apache2 from my system. I reinstalled apache2 using command "apt-get install apache2" but after doing so it could no longer open .php files, shows a blank page instead. I've set the necessary permissions (given -R 777 to /etc and /var/www). I've also ran the command "apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0" and restarted apache several times, nothing works. Can anyone help?

PS: I was originally trying to run phpmyadmin, before purging I was able to run it but after reinstalling it threw errors, thence I discovered my server was not able to execute any php file.
Additionally, when I access the file (home.php) via localhost/home.php it shows a blank page but if follow the path file:///var/www/html/home.php it brings a pop up that asks me to either save or open the script.

Comment: check apache logs

Comment: What do you see if you put a php file with `<?php print 123; ?>` in your webroot and access that page with the browser? 

Blank page could mean, that your page throws errors but error displaying is disabled

Comment: nothing, still a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is the apache-php-mod is not well installed,I suggest you purge remove all apache and php package,then reinstall them.

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get purge php
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then,find all apache2 or php files, and remove them,you can do it by using find command,be carefully when do this！

```
sudo find / -name apache2
```

At last,you can reinstall them